# Secure FTP Download not working in UWP

Tags: download, uwp, ftp, file-transfer

I tried using BackgroundDownloader class to download file from secure FTP server, but it doesn't download and also didn't throw any exception.

The below GetResponseInformation() is returning null.

I'm providing input URL as below:
ftp://username:password@hostIP/test.pdf

Code below:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(ftpUrlBox.Text.Trim());
            StorageFile storageFile = await pickedFolder.CreateFileAsync("DownloadedFile.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(uri, storageFile);

            ftpBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            await downloadOperation.StartAsync();
            ftpBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            ResponseInformation responseInformation = downloadOperation.GetResponseInformation();
            ftpStatusText.Text = responseInformation != null ? responseInformation.StatusCode.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Kindly help how to download and upload from and to secure FTP server in UWP.

Note: If I use some 3rd party nuget library, FTP(S) download is working. But not with above UWP code.

Comment: Is the size of  test.pdf greater than 1M?

Comment: No, it's just 140KB.. Is there any file size restriction? Also it says "ftps" uri scheme is not supported, So i'm using "ftp" scheme with credentials in the ftp url.. Will this work in uwp?

Comment: Yep, I have found some Ftp download [tool class](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/C-/blob/master/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloader/FTP/FTPDownloadManager.cs#L232) that you could refer.

Comment: Is FTP Upload not supported using UWP API's?

Comment: It is not support with BackgroundTransfer, For upload file you could refer [this](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/ftp-endeavor-ii-upload-and-download-files/).